# How can I detect that a "Screen Time" process has crashed?

Tags: ios, swift, screen-time

The issue:

Create a simple two tabs view:

```swift
 TabView {
     Tab1View()
           .tabItem {
                        Label("Tab 1", systemImage: "1.circle.fill")
                    }
     Tab2View()
           .tabItem {
                        Label("Tab 2", systemImage: "2.circle.fill")
                    }
     }
```

Each tab has a different "Screen Time" report, e.g.

```swift
struct Tab2View: View {
    var body: some View {
            DeviceActivityReport(Utils.weeklyContext, filter: Utils.filterWeekly)
    }
}
```

When you switch the tabs quickly, the "Screen Time" process crashes, leaving both reports blank.

Here is a video illustrating the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrRpohf9tmw&ab_channel=MarcinCzech

A simple project with code to replicate:

https://github.com/AndroidGecko/Screen-Time/tree/screen_time_issues

I have filed it via a Feedback Assistant, but I can see that some apps have somehow found a workaround to this issue — so wondering how they did it.

The size of the "DeviceReportActivity" remains the same (it's just blank), so there is no way to tell if it crashed.

However, apps like [Jomo](https://jomo.so/) or [Opal](https://www.opal.so/) have tabs with two "Screen Time" reports.
And if you switch tabs quickly, you can see it breaking, but somehow they make it re-appear. We can refresh the view using `.id()` on the report, but I cannot see a way of detecting when the report (screen time process) has crashed. Forcing a new `.id` on each tab switch is not feasible as it re-fetches the whole report (Jomo and Opal don't do it).

Question:
How can I detect that a "Screen Time" process has crashed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is originating from your third party library, `RiveRuntime`.

The `DeviceActivityReport` is not technically crashing because when I reproduce the problem and then look on the list of crash dumps, there is no crash dump.

I am able to reproduce the problem reliably just by having:

```
VStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text("Rive View in Screen Time Extension")
                DeviceActivityReport(context, filter: filter)
                DeviceActivityReport(context, filter: filter)
                DeviceActivityReport(context, filter: filter)
                ...
```

However when I did system profiling, which requires a Release build, I noticed an issue with your configuration:

```
ld: warning: linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Screen_Time-blyljiictkbafcchdezmsppdawwr/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/RiveRuntime.framework/RiveRuntime
```

When I remove the use of the `RiveRuntime.framework` I can no longer get it to fail.  The device reports come out correctly each time.

Comment: Hey, thank you for looking into it Faisal!
It looks like you were using the `main` branch from the link above (which shows a different issue with Rive). The sample code from the link in question points to the `screen_time_issues` branch, which has no Rive framework. Regarding crashing — If you look at the console output from the `screen_time_issues`, you will see the "Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9" message, and if you attach a debugger to the "MonitorExtension" process, you will see that the process is killed. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: I tried again but with branch `screen_time_issues` but I cannot get it to crash.  However, I've only an iPhone 11, not iPhone 14 to test it on.  If you can retrieve the crash dump, please post it here.  Also worth running Console app and filter process:DeviceActivityReportService and cross-compare iPhone11 vs 14.  I see also from Instruments->System Activity DeviceActivityReportService runs concurrently across CPUs so potentially there is a multi-thread issue.